# update in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

I really haven't been able to find an example that includes all the keywords in
the update postgres command.

The syntax is :

```
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
SET{ column = {expression | DEFAULT}}
[,...][FROM fromlist][WHERE condition]
```

no idea about how to use only, alias, exp or default, fromlist.
managed so far to understand and use only the below. Need help on how to use 
the rest of the keywords.

```
UPDATE cds SET temp_min = temp_min-1,
temp_max = temp_min + 20, rainfall = 0
WHERE (river = 'Mal') AND (datac > '2010-12-12')
AND (datac < '2011-12-12');
```

Comment: You will find out when you need them. What you do in your example is the most common update.

Comment: Yeah I can do the most common update , cause it's written bellow the example .     I want to know how to use the rest of them (an example would help , something for me to expand on)      and  "You will find out when you need them"  kinda beats the question so hillarious and not the first person who told me that :)) in the last 24h.

Comment: This isn't Jeopardy where you give the answer and we ask the questions.

Comment: so funny Jeopardy is a Us tv show right? im from europe :D

Comment: But I understand the <>      answer/question     :(        anyway  if you can help i would apreciate it .

Comment: Have you even tried to look at the manual page for `UPDATE`? It explains everything. If you don't find alias or only in the docs only then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to read the docs carefully. PostgreSQL has a really good documentation. Regarding 'ONLY' it [states](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html):

> If ONLY is specified before the table name, matching rows are updated
>   in the named table only. **If ONLY is not specified, matching rows are
>   also updated in any tables inheriting from the named table**.
>   Optionally, * can be specified after the table name to explicitly
>   indicate that descendant tables are included.

Since PostgreSQL supports [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-inheritance.html), the UPDATE statement may also change the rows of the tables that inherit the specified table, which may be undesirable.

**`{expression | DEFAULT}`** means that you can assign a column to either **NULL** (default) or any expression, e.g. `1+1`, `power(2,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example update statement that uses the elements that you asked about:

```
update foobar as foo -- "foo" is an alias for the table foobar
   set      
     column_1 = default, -- this sets the column to the default value defined in the CREATE TABLE statement
     column_2 = (column_3 + column_4) * 42-- this is an expression
from other_table -- this is the fromlist
where other_table.fid = foo.id -- this uses the "foo" alias
```

The keyword `ONLY` is only of interest if you are using [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html).